# Is it safe to store a connection (effectively a pointer) in memcache?

Tags: php, python, memcached

I am using memcached on a web site, and I am currently needing to open connections to a database and socket each time a function is called. In the case of the db connection, I am having to decide at runtime, which database to connect to.

Because of the (default) stateless nature of web apps, I am having to tear down (i.e. close) the connection after each function call. I am wondering if it is possible to store (i.e. cache) the socket connection and the database connections in memcache - do that I have a pool of db connections and a socket connection already open that I can use whenever the function is called.

Is this safe ?

**[[Additional Info]]**

I will be interfacing to memcached primarily, with PHP and Python

BTW - memcached is running on the same machine (so physical address issues should not arise).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both languages support database connections which live beyond the lifetime of a single request. Don't use memcache for that!

Comment: I suspected that about the db connections in any case - however my real concern is with the socket connections - they are quite "expensive".

Answer (score 0):

> I am wondering if it is possible to store (i.e. cache) the socket connection and the database connections in memcache

No.

Comment: Any particular reason why (I like to know why I can or can't do something) - for instance, is there any where in the formal docs that states you cant do this?. I looked in the source code and the stored value is a stored in a union which holds an int64 (which is what a memory address is on my hardware) - so long as memcache is running on the same machine as the client that stored it (and consumes it), I can't see what the prob is - unless I'm missing something.